# how to get long text to next line when it overflows out of browser screen

Tags: html, css

I am not familiar with css style and properties. I want the text to appear in next line instead of flowing outside browser screen.

I have shown what I need and what is happening currently.

[image]

[image]
Pic #1 shows what is currently happening but I want to happen what is shown in pic#2.

I tried word-wrap :break-all;   overflow-wrap: break-word !important; but nothing worked.
Note: I have set margin 0 auto;

**template.html**

```
  <div class="rightDiv">

   <div class="customerText" align="center">
      <b>
        Customer Number (Customer Name)
      </b>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <p id="spandiv">10122019 (tjwmxuwmiihcxdfryfgfhrunlfsxrkhvmyqjjuwjddknjaybnrobpzferxaenxzenbckmlqqzesvfbnnsxwydfbzgbaxkccvoplgjxbikxjifojjmvqxmbjbrtmvbngq)</p>
    </div>
```

**template.css**

```
.rightDiv {
 position: relative;
 right: 350px;
 height: 80px;
 width: 250px;
}

.content{
  width:50%;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0px;
  text-align:center;
  top:10px;

}
#spandiv {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:11px;
  background-color: #232F34;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  opacity:1;
  top:5px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word !important;

}
```

Comment: Add overflow hidden, it will work.

Comment: Hi, I want the overflow text to appear in next line and not hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `overflow-wrap: break-word` to work, the `display` should be set to `block` and also opacity must not be 0. Set it to a very small value like 0.001

```
p#spandiv {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.001;
    overflow-wrap: break-word
}
```

Here's a pen demonstrating this: [CSS force word break](https://codepen.io/kwameopareasiedu/pen/xxbLMNB)

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, I tried your solution but still the text flows outside browser window

Comment: I went through your styling and it seems the `opacity: 0` is breaking it...  Setting it to something like 0.001 resolves it...

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have changed opacity to 1

Comment: Even with the `display: block` on the `p#spandiv` selector...??

Comment: I think this is causing problem

Comment: Actually the problem is the `position: relative` on the `.rightDiv`. Change it to `position: absolute` to fix the problem. I've updated the codepen sample to demonstrate this...

Comment: Using `position: relative` with `right: 350px` will always shift everything to the left (out of view of the window). Using `position: absolute` will make the element 350px from the right side of the window...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205039/discussion-between-karansys-and-kwame-opare-asiedu).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rightDiv {
 position: relative;
 height: 80px;
 width: 60%;
}

.content{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0px;
  top:10px;

}
#spandiv {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:11px;
  background-color: #232F34;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  opacity:1;
  top:5px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightDiv">

   <div class="customerText" align="center">
      <b>
        Customer Number (Customer Name)
      </b>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <p id="spandiv">10122019 (tjwmxuwmiihcxdfryfgfhrunlfsxrkhvmyqjjuwjddknjaybnrobpzferxaenxzenbckmlqqzesvfbnnsxwydfbzgbaxkccvoplgjxbikxjifojjmvqxmbjbrtmvbngq)</p>
    </div>
```